# Opening and closing custom console components

Tags: custom-console-components

We are leveraging a 3rd party soft phone. We also have a custom console component that we open when the call ends. We do this using the setCustomConsoleComponentVisible() method. The issue is, when popping this component open, it does not auto-minimize the phone component. However, when manually opening our custom console component the phone component automatically minimizes. Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setVisible to collapse the phone component if it's the openCTI softphone:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_setvisible.htm.

If that doesn't work, you can try getting a reference to the console component's button via document.getElementById and calling click() on it.